# Take String From Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I have an input field with one button. I store value of input in array. 
My console.log output has below result 
[image]

How can take the String "JOHN" from this array? 
My code is:

```
var category = $('#customer_name_search').val();
var len = category.length;
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

    var test = category[i];
    arr.push(test);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: doesn't `category` hold the string value that you're after?

Comment: Simple: `["J","O","H","N"].join("")`

Comment: You can use `myAray.join()` to combine array values together

Comment: Yes but i want use array for other reason..But i find the result of my problem.

Comment: @ZerobyteHD yes man i find this..thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `join()` method

```js
var category = $('#customer_name_search').val();
var len = category.length;
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

    var test = category[i];
    arr.push(test);
}

console.log(arr.join(''));
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is some documentation

Comment: the correct is console.log(arr.join(""));

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Join().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
const elements = ['Fire', 'Air', 'Water'];

console.log(elements.join());
// expected output: "Fire,Air,Water"

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: "FireAirWater"

console.log(elements.join('-'));
// expected output: "Fire-Air-Water"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array.join` to merge the strings in an array

```js
const array = ["J", "O", "H", "N"];
const merged = array.join("");
```

so the result will be `"JOHN"`

Answer (score -1):

You just need to join the array by using array function(join).
Check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var category = $('#customer_name_search').val();
var str = category.join('');
```

Comment: This splits a string into an array. The question is how to combine and array to a string